# Customizar IdentityUserClaim

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, owin

Estou tentando customizar a tabela de Claims do Identity, através da classe IdentityUserClaim.

Estou utilizando um mapeamento, através da classe EntityTypeConfiguration, mas recebo o erro:

A configuration for type 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUserClaim' has already been added. To reference the existing configuration use the Entity() or ComplexType() methods.

O método OnModelCreating de DbContext, está assim:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ApplicationUserClaimConfiguration());
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ApplicationIdentityUserClaimConfiguration());

    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ApplicationIdentityRoleConfiguration());
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ApplicationRoleConfiguration());

    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ApplicationUserConfiguration());
}
```

A classe ApplicationIdentityUserClaimConfiguration está assim:

```
public class ApplicationIdentityUserClaimConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<IdentityUserClaim>
{
    public ApplicationIdentityUserClaimConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("UserClaim");
    }
}
```

A classe ApplicationUserClaimConfiguration mapeia a classe ApplicationUserClaim : IdentityUserClaim para a mesma tabela UserClaim.

Alguém sabe como resolver este problema?

Obrigado.

Comment: Parece que vocês esta criando duas vezes a mesma tabela testa apenas com um configuration apenas

Answer (score 0):

aqui vai um exemplo de mapeamento pode fazer separado do mesmo jeito que você fez mais esse modo também funciona.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
 {
 base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
 //sobrescrever a entidade IdentityUser pela entidade Usuario
 modelBuilder.Entity<Usuario>().ToTable("Usuarios")
 .Property(u => u.Id).HasColumnName("IdUsuario");
 modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("Perfis");
 modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("UsuariosPerfis");
 modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("UsuariosLogin");
 modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("UsuariosClaims");
 }
```

Comment: Então @Eduardo, esse método funciona, mas quero manter as configurações separadas. Por isso criei a classe ApplicationIdentityUserClaimConfiguration.

Removi uma das configurações, no caso, ApplicationIdentityUserClaimConfiguration. Mas o Identity criou duas tabelas: AspNetUserClaims e UserClaim.

Se deixo a ApplicationIdentityUserClaimConfiguration e removo a ApplicationUserClaimConfiguration, dá o mesmo erro anterior.

Só para constar, a classe ApplicationUserClaimConfiguration herda de EntityTypeConfiguration<ApplicationUserClaim>. E ApplicationUserClaim herda de IdentityUserClaim.

Comment: sim realmente fazendo mapeamento com fluent api separado fica melhor ,pelo que parece criou mesma tabela duas vezes so com nomes diferentes tenta criar apenas ApplicationIdentityUserClaimConfiguration  ou tenta fazer no mapeamento de forma diferente  criando uma entidade que herde de IdentityUserClaim e o mapeamento seria para esse entidade .

Comment: No caso, isso não funcionou @Eduardo. O que você disse, foi exatamente o que fiz. 

Esta é a classe ApplicationUserClaimConfiguration:

`public class ApplicationUserClaimConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<ApplicationUserClaim> 
{
   public ApplicationUserClaimConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("UserClaim");
    }
}`

Eu só criei ApplicationIdentityUserClaimConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<IdentityUserClaim>, por causa do que diz nesse artigo:

[http://eduardopires.net.br/2015/02/customizando-nomes-tabelas-campos-asp-net-identity/]

Comment: Desculpe @Eduardo, acho que faltou informação. No caso, eu faço a configuração das duas classes:  IdentityUserClaim e ApplicationUserClaim, que herda de IdentityUserClaim.

Que ficaram respectivamente como ApplicationIdentityUserClaimConfiguration e ApplicationUserClaimConfiguration.

Ficou claro? rsrs

Comment: então no seu mapeamento você mapeia ApplicationUserClaim não  identityUserClaim

Comment: Mas se eu mapeio apenas ApplicationUserClaim, como abaixo, ele cria duas tabelas: AspNetUserClaims e UserClaim "/

`protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            //modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ApplicationIdentityUserClaimConfiguration());

            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ApplicationUserClaimConfiguration());

        }`